# "resolve:fallback" being ignored in react web3 app

Tags: webpack, compiler-errors, web3js

Every time I start up my app I get the following errors:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\willk\WillKristiansen Dropbox\Will Kristiansen\PC\Documents\Development\react-web3\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

So I did what it asked me to do and I created a fallback for every error that I got.

```
module.exports = {

    resolve: {
        fallback: { stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify') }
    },

    resolve: {
        fallback: { crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify') }
    },

    resolve: {
        fallback: { assert: require.resolve('assert/') }
    },

    resolve: {
        fallback: { http: require.resolve('stream-http') }
    },

    resolve: {
        fallback: { https: require.resolve('https-browserify') }
    },

    resolve: {
        fallback: { url: require.resolve('url/') }
    },

    resolve: {
        fallback: { os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser') }
    },
}
```

assert and url are the only ones that worked in fixing the error, but all the other fallbacks were ignored entirely. I have tried variations of the syntax such as:

```
resolve: {
        fallback: { "stream": require.resolve('stream-browserify') }
    },

but that didn't work either. I've updated npm, web3, uninstalled and reinstalled stream-browserify locally and globally, updated node, etc. I am a very new programmer so I don't know what else to try. Has anyone had this issue before?
```

Comment: Minor fix! I was able to fix the stream-browserify error by using:
```
NPM install stream
```

But npm install crypto didn't work so I still have 7 errors

Comment: If you still have an issue, please [edit] your question to update it. If not, you can delete the question.